# setwd in R - mapped drive?

Tags: r

Sorry I am very new to this, so am confused. I am working on a project that requires me to analyze data that is on a shared drive. I cannot make a copy of the dataset. How do I load this dataset in R? It's also a SAS file I'll need to read into R.

The file is smb://department.university.edu/lab101/me/dataset/file.xpt Setwd(smb://department.university.edu/lab101/me/dataset) doesn't work, but am not sure what would here.

Answer (score 2):

First, Your setwd receives a character string as file path:

`setwd("smb:\\department.university.edu\lab101\me\dataset")`

Then you can read the file like mentioned here:

```
# save SAS dataset in trasport format
libname out xport 'c:/mydata.xpt';
data out.mydata;
set sasuser.mydata;
run;

# in R 
library(Hmisc)
mydata <- sasxport.get("file.xpt")
# character variables are converted to R factors
```

Reference: http://www.statmethods.net/input/importingdata.html

Comment: When I put the setwd as you suggested, I get an error message: Error in setwd("smb://department.university.edu/lab101/me/dataset"). Cannot change working directory.

Comment: I've updated the code with backslash - please check now

Comment: @vconfused101 did this help?  I'm running into the same issue without success.